# How can the BIOS larger than 64KB today?

Tags: x86, bios

AFAIK, BIOS size is limited to a segment size (0xFFFF). But many BIOS are larger that 64KB today, usually over 10MB. How can it do that?

Answer (score 6):

The 64KiB limitation has always been an hardware limitation, not a software one.
The main point is re-steering the memory access from the memory to the firmware Flash ROM.
This is all it takes to allow for bigger Flash ROMs but the history is complex.

---

The CPU accesses the firmware (either for fetching instructions or data) through at least one external chip.
A modern hierarchy is like this one:

```
Core --[QPI/UPI]--> System Agent --[DMI]--> PCH --[SPI/LPC]--> FLASH ROM
```

An older one is:

```
CPU --[FSB]--> North Bridge/MCH --[DMI/Proprietary]--> South Bridge/ICH --[LPC] --> FLASH ROM
```

An even older one is:

```
CPU --[BUS]--> System Controller --> FLASH ROM
```

*Note*: The Flash ROM is usually connected to the LPC through a SuperIO chip or an Embedded Controller.

To allow the CPU to reach firmware, some of the memory addresses are stolen and redirected to the Flash ROM.
This is done by configuring all the intermediate nodes between the CPU and the Flash ROM.

The size of this window was set to be either 64KiB or 128KiB (corresponding to the ranges `0xf0000-0xfffff` or `0xe0000-0xfffff`) but this was a design decision (that allowed to have 640KiB of RAM and 320/256KiB of expansion ROMs).
One could have designed the window to be 512KiB or more (though RAM would have been limited).

Anyway the window was set to 64KiB and changing that would have broken the software, so it was not (and it is not) extended.
When the 386 came out the CPU could address more than 1MiB (+64KiB-16B), actually this was "prototyped" in the 286 with a 24-bit address space, and an opportunity came.

At power on the CPU starts fetching instructions at `CS:IP = 0xf000:0x0fff`, like a 16-bit CPU, but (thanks to how segment registers work internally) this logical address is not translated to `0xffff0` (as it was the case for 16-bit CPU) but to `0xfffffff0` (16 bytes below the 4GiB limit).
This is done for backward compatibility (the `CS:IP` pair visible to the software is unchanged) and, at the same time, to allow mapping bigger Flash ROM.
Of course, the addresses near the 4GiB need to be redirected (stolen) to the Flash ROM too.

A 4GiB address space is not as impacted as a 1MiB address space by the size of the firmware window, so the window at 4GiB is larger.
The size of this window can be made as large as needed (in compatibility with other system devices) but there is a catch (actually two).

1. At 4GiB-18MiB there is a not-always-accessible area shadowed by the LAPIC (a CPU internal block), this area is moveable and can be disabled but by default it is at 4GiB-18MiB.
   So a Flash ROM of, say, 30MiB, would be partially inaccessible.
2. The PCH SPI module supports a window of at most 8MiB.

How can a firmware be 20MiB?
Today a firmware is made primarily of four components:

- The UEFI/BIOS
- The Intel ME
- The 1Gbs ethernet
- The RAID controller

The windows discussed above are only for the UEFI/BIOS.
The ME Firmware has its own window, the ethernet and raid controller are PCIe devices and can take advantage of any PCI window.

---

In synthesis, the firmware is fragmented into multiple components, most of which follow the PCI(e) design. The rest have special memory windows of large enough size.

So why it is still said that the BIOS is limited to a segment size?
Because when the CPU boots from `0xfffffff0` it is actually in 16-bit/32-bit mixed mode, it has only 16 bytes before the "end of the memory" (before the 4GiB limit) but any far jump will reload `CS` by the 16-bit rule, confining the CPU in the lower 1MiB limit.
So the old 64KiB/128KiB window still exists and it is mapped to the same area of the flash.
This lets the firmware be bigger than 16B and configure the system as needed (e.g. map only the 16-bit services to the lower window).

Comment: Does that mean the UEFI/BIOS is still 64KB, but the other components of the firmware' have their own limitations?

Comment: The 16-bit interface of the UEFI/BIOS is still 64/128KiB. That was enough back then and it is still enough considering that those interface barely changed. The code in this window can switch to 32/64-bit mode and use the upper windows.

Comment: I think I've caught your point. The firmware can dynamically adjust the 'window' to get any part of itself being mapped to the system address map, right?

Comment: @noinput Yes, it can do so

Answer (score 0):

Modern firmware doesn't run in 16-bit real mode; it switches to protected or long mode soon after booting.  (And it can contain non-code images).

(This is a somewhat hand-wavy answer because I don't know the specific details off the top of my head.  I think related questions have come up on Stack Overflow before about where the BIOS is mapped and/or what CS:IP the CPU jumps to on bootup).

If you tell your firmware to load a legacy BIOS boot sector (i.e. to boot in legacy mode instead of UEFI) then it has to switch back to real mode.

In that case IDK how much the firmware keeps loaded; it might switch into protected mode and back when handling `int 10h` and other legacy PC BIOS calls, to get access to memory that real-mode code can't have overwritten.